# Create a graph at the start of an application in kivy (NoneType object has no Atribute "Get_Screen")

Tags: python, graph, kivy

I have created a small kivy app for summarizing my Grades and everything works just fine until the point where i want to display a graph at the start of the application so i am able to display the graph correctly on a press of a button(click Mathe and then back it calls the function) however trying to call the same function at the start results in: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'" although there are some answers for this problem sadly none of them worked for me :( maybe i have implemented them wrongly i would be grateful if someone could help.
here the important parts of the code:

```
class MainWindow(Screen,object):


def Allgemeinepunkte(self, *args):
    print("nice")
    self.manager.get_screen("main").ids.Graph.clear_widgets()
    global Alist 
    with open ('Allgemein.txt', 'r') as m:
        Alist = m.read().splitlines()

    Alist = [int(item) for item in Alist]


    AAnzahlNoten = []
    x = 0
    for i in Alist:
        AAnzahlNoten.append(x+1)
        x = x+1 

    plt.clf()
    plt.gcf() 
    plt.plot(AAnzahlNoten,Alist)
    plt.tight_layout() 
    self.manager.get_screen('main').ids.Graph.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
```

and the App itself:

```
class MyMainApp(App):
def build(self):
    Window.clearcolor = (0.08,0.12,0.17,1)
    kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
    return kv

def on_start(self, **kwargs):
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.Allgemeinepunkte()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyMainApp()
    app.run()
```

And the error:

```
 File "c:\Users\denis\Documents\VSCode\main.py", line 42, in Allgemeinepunkte
     self.manager.get_screen("main").ids.Graph.clear_widgets()
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screen'
```

Comment: Here the full code on GitHub: https://github.com/Deimos000/KIvyapp#readme

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App`:

```
def on_start(self, **kwargs):
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.Allgemeinepunkte()
```

This method creates a new instance of `MainWindow`, and calls its `Allgemeinepunkte()` method. But since the new instance of `MainWindow` is not added to a `ScreenManager`, its `manager` property is `None`. You need to access the actual instance of `MainWindow` that is in your GUI. Probably, need to access the `MainWindow` instance as:

```
def on_start(self, **kwargs):
    mw = self.root.get_screen('main')
    mw.Allgemeinepunkte()
```